# Custom Angular directive to hide or show elements in multiple views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working with Angular js into a modular application. When a user for a company enters  the app, it determines the number of motor boats that have that company and in the menu view shows a multiselect that enables to select one or other motor boat to manage it.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn m-t-xs">
  <li>
    <a ng-click="changeBoat(boatInfo)" class="ng-binding">
            182 /  ASTROBOAT
        </a>
    </li>
  <li>
        <a ng-click="changeBoat(boatInfo)" class="ng-binding">
            180 /  START BOAT
        </a>
    </li>
  <li>
        <a ng-click="changeBoat(boatInfo)" class="ng-binding">
            178 /  STORM BOAT
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And into dashboard module in the same screen, the app shows a table with the information of all boats. The point is, when the company only have one boat there is not sense to show the selector or the table. I want to use diferent components in these case. So I am thinking in create a directive `user-if-single-boat`, which will hide or show components in all the views, something like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn m-t-xs" user-if-single-boat> ...
<table class="..." user-if-single-boat> ...
```

I also know that maybe I can do that with a `ng-if` that validates a `$rootScope` variable (`<ul class="dropdown-menu animated fadeIn m-t-xs" ng-if='isMultiBoats'>`), but I don't want to use the `$rootScope` and I need to validate these atttibute through all my application modules.

Comment: Who says you need to use `ng-if` _with the `$rootScope`_? Any other variable from a narrower scope should do fine.

Comment: Yeah @Thomas, but is a variable that I want to set just one time and have it available always. Thanks.